# How to access insertedIds array of BulkWriteResult in insertMany API of mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulkinsert

`insertMany` API in mongoose returns a Promise object but i am using the callback version of it.

```
let options = {
    "ordered": true
};

MySchema.insertMany(documents, options, function (error, docs) {
    if(error) {
        // i need insertedIds array here
    } else {
        // do someting
    }
});
```

when i stringify the `error` object, I can see the JSON as shown below:

```
{
   "ok":1,
   "writeErrors":[
        "code":11000,
        "index":1,
        // there will be some more failure details here
   ],
   "writeConcernErrors":[],
   "insertedIds":[
      {
         "index":0,
         "_id":"5be183914d0c761eeadda8c4"
      },
      {
         "index":1,
         "_id":"5be183914d0c761eeadda8c5"
      },
      {
         "index":2,
         "_id":"5be183914d0c761eeadda8c6"
      }
   ],
   "nInserted":1,
   "nUpserted":0,
   "nMatched":0,
   "nModified":0,
   "nRemoved":0,
   "upserted":[]
}
```

but when i try to get the `insertedIds` array it returns `undefined`. I did bit of a research and found that the `error` object returned is actually not a JSON object but something related to `BulkWriteResult` or `BulkWriteError`.

> So now how can i get the values in `insertedIds` array? Please help.

P.S.: using mongoose version : ^5.2.17

Comment: `{ ordered: true }` will reject the entire batch of operations on any failure. So nothing gets "inserted" and the key will actually be missing from the returned object. That's by design. See [Ordered and Unordered Bulk Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#ordered-and-unordered-bulk-operations) in the documentation.

Comment: yes i know how ordered works, but setting it to false also does not work

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to produce a "reproducible" example of the problem. So a short listing that inserts some data and errors part way though. Give us a listing so we can all reproduce it ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Because `result.insertedIds` is getter, try this `let insertedIds = error.result.getInsertedIds()` or `let insertedIds = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error.result)).insertedIds;`